# Using Hive with Pig

Tags: apache-pig, hive

My hive query has multiple outer joins and takes very long to execute. I was wondering if it would make sense to break it into multiple smaller queries and use pig to work the transformations.

Is there a way I could query hive tables or read hive table data within a pig script?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The goal of the [Howl project](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/Howl) is to allow Pig and Hive to share a single metadata repository. Once Howl is mature, you'll be able to run PigLatin and HiveQL queries over the 
same tables. For now, you can try to work with the data as it is stored in HDFS.

Note that Howl has been renamed to [HCatalog](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/hcatalog.html).

Comment: Thanks, will wait for Howl :)