# Reading hive table using Pig script

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am trying to read hive table using PIG script but when I run a pig code to read a table in hive its giving me following error:

```
2014-02-12 15:48:36,143 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf  
    -hive-site.xml not found on CLASSPATH 2014-02-12 15:49:10,781 [main] ERROR
    org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997:  Unable to recreate
    exception from backed error: Error: Found class 
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskAttemptContext, but interface was expected
```

*(Ignore newlines and whitespace added for readability)*

Hadoop version
1.1.1

Hive version
0.9.0

Pig version
0.10.0

```
    Pig code
    a = LOAD '/user/hive/warehouse/test' USING 
    org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.HiveColumnarLoader('name string');
```

Is it due to some version mismatch ?

Comment: Could you please share the full trace?Also, do have a look at HCatalog.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741120/running-pig-query-over-data-stored-in-hive

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use `hcatalog` to access hive metadata in pig?
Check [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog+LoadStore) for an example