# How can a hive table's data can be read using PiG latin

Tags: hive, apache-pig

How can a hive table's data can be read using PiG latin.

I have a table in hive and I want to generate a `~` or `|` separated file and for that I am trying to use PiG to generate the file.

Comment: Possible duplicate [Running-pig-query-over-data-stored-in-hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741120/running-pig-query-over-data-stored-in-hive)

Answer (score 0):

You not even need to use PIG, hive can export the data into the local filesystem

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/tmp/local_out' SELECT a.* FROM pokes a;
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-SQLOperations

But if you'd like to use PIG use the HCatLoader

```
A = LOAD 'hivedb.hivetable' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

Comment: But how could I put a separator of my choice

Comment: if you export from hive you can set the saparator: 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
if you'll plan to use pig to export the data set the separator to the pigstorage:
 PigStorage(',', '-schema')